# Arrange a dataframe with close to a value order - R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
> dummy
   index ARMA             ME
1      4  2,3 -0.00764558073
2      4  3,1 -0.00017109916
3      4  3,2 -0.00038884805
4      4  3,3 -0.00246287881
5      3  1,3 -0.00004263228
6      1  0,1  0.00046965874
7      1  0,2  0.00105372919
8      1  1,0  0.00018798497
9      1  2,1  0.00112475686
10     1  2,2 -0.00121912970
11     1  3,0  0.00181957426
```

And the ARMA column is some kind of ID.
This dataset is arranged by index from 4 to 1 (descending order)

I want to arrange the dataset by index (descending) **and** first the ME value closest to 0

So this would be the desired output:

```
> dummy
   index ARMA             ME
1      4  3,1 -0.00017109916
2      4  3,2 -0.00038884805
3      4  3,3 -0.00246287881
4      4  2,3 -0.00764558073
5      3  1,3 -0.00004263228
6      1  1,0  0.00018798497
7      1  0,1  0.00046965874
8      1  0,2  0.00105372919
9      1  2,1  0.00112475686
10     1  2,2 -0.00121912970
11     1  3,0  0.00181957426
```

Thanks in advance!!

---

Data:

```
> dput(dummy)
structure(list(index = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), ARMA = c("2,3", "3,1", "3,2", "3,3", "1,3", "0,1", "0,2", 
"1,0", "2,1", "2,2", "3,0"), ME = c(-0.00764558072775317, -0.000171099162494111, 
-0.000388848046105807, -0.00246287880997775, -0.0000426322805130549, 
0.000469658740281779, 0.001053729189345, 0.000187984966060834, 
0.00112475685730634, -0.00121912969696577, 0.00181957426209449
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
dummy[ order(-dummy$index, abs(dummy$ME)), ]
#    index ARMA             ME
# 2      4  3,1 -0.00017109916
# 3      4  3,2 -0.00038884805
# 4      4  3,3 -0.00246287881
# 1      4  2,3 -0.00764558073
# 5      3  1,3 -0.00004263228
# 8      1  1,0  0.00018798497
# 6      1  0,1  0.00046965874
# 7      1  0,2  0.00105372919
# 9      1  2,1  0.00112475686
# 10     1  2,2 -0.00121912970
# 11     1  3,0  0.00181957426
```

To fill this out a little ...

- if the sort direction (ascending or descending) for all fields is the same, then `order(...)` or `order(..., decreasing=TRUE)` will suffice;
- if there is mixed-direction and all fields to sort on are `numeric` or `integer`, then one can *negate* the fields needing descending order and keep the other fields as-is, such as `order(asc1, -desc1, -desc3, asc4)`;
- if there is mixed-direction, then all other fields that are not `numeric`/`integer` and require decreasing
- `order(...)` accepts one or more fields, and has the optional `decreasing=` argument that, when `TRUE`, will reverse the whole sort order; if there is mixed sorting (some ascending, some descending), then we may need to get creative;
- `logical` fields always sort `FALSE`-first, since false is effectively 0 and true is 1; if a logical field sort order should be reversed (true first), then negate it with either the negative `-` or the logical negation `!`, as in `order(-lgl)` or `order(!lgl)`;
- number fields (literally `integer` and `numeric`) can be individually reversed by negating them, as in `order(-num)`;
- any other field (including `character`, `Date`, and `POSIXt`) that needs to be reversed will need to be reversed using the negative `rank(.)` of that field, such as `order(-rank(chr, ties.method="min"))`.

With a more complex example, if we have a data frame with fields `num`, `char`, and `date` that are what class their names suggest, and we want to sort: by num *ascending*, by char *descending*, and by date *ascending*, then we would use `order(num, -rank(char, ties.method="min"), date)`.